# SQL Join multiple table without repetition

Tags: t-sql

I've got 3 tables

Table A

```
----------------------
| ID| Data1 | Data2 |
---------------------
| 1  |John   | 2021 |
| 2  |Steve  | 2020 |
```

Table B

```
----------------------
|Row|ID|Value1|Value2|
----------------------
|1  |1 |iR3000|0.5   |
|2  |1 |iRC252|0.7   |
|3  |2 |Dr2000|0.4   |
```

Table C

```
----------------------
|Row|ID|Value3|Value4|
----------------------
|1  |1 |aaaaaa|12345 |
|2  |1 |bbbbbb|6789  |
```

My goal is to add a result like this :

```
-------------------------------------------------
| ID| Data1 | Data2 |Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4|
-------------------------------------------------
| 1  |John   | 2021 |iR3000|0.5   |aaaaaa|12345 |
| 1  |John   | 2021 |iRC252|0.7   |bbbbbb|6789  |
| 2  |Steve  | 2020 |Dr2000|0.4   |null  |null  |
```

Actually with my query, the ID 1 is duplicate 4 times.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT 
   a.id, a.data1,a.data2
  ,b.value1, b.value2
  ,c.value3,c.value4
FROM TableA a 
JOIN TableB b
ON b.ID=a.ID
JOIN TableC c
ON c.ID=a.ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you had was close; only the JOIN to `TableC` was wrong. It needs to be an OUTER JOIN and also match on the `Row` column:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Data1, a.Data2, b.Value1, b.Value2, c.Value3, c.Value4
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b on b.ID = a.ID
LEFT JOIN TableC c on c.ID = b.ID AND c.Row = b.Row
```

---

Update based on the comment:

> I cannot use row column cause they are not always match with the same number.

Okay. If the `Row` column at least exists, we can still work with that to create projections that might be more consistent between tables:

```
With TableB2 AS (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by ID order by row) As Row2
    FROM TableB
),
TableC2 As (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by ID order by row) As Row2
    FROM TableC
)
SELECT a.ID, a.Data1, a.Data2, b.Value1, b.Value2, c.Value3, c.Value4
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB2 b on b.ID = a.ID
LEFT JOIN TableC2 c on c.ID = b.ID AND c.Row = b.Row
```

What we *cannot* do is rely on the order of the records on disk or the insertion order. There **MUST** be some field to indicate, e.g. the `iR3000` row in `TableB` relates to the `aaaaaa` row in `TableC` rather than the `bbbbbb` row.

The order records appear in the table *is not good enough*. Databases are based on relational set theory, so what we think of as "Tables" are more-formally defined as "Unordered Relations". Note the word "unordered" in that definition. While table order may seem to be stable over stretches, *databases are free to re-ordered the rows on disk after insertion.* They can and will do this to make queries more efficient, conform better with indexes, fill up pages, etc.

Comment: Well, i cannot use row column cause they are not always match with the same number. it was juts for my example. Sorry

Comment: @Chris You **MUST** have some column to relate, eg the `iR3000` row in TableB with the `aaaaaa` row in TableC. The order they appear in the table _is not good enough_. Databases are based on relational set theory, so what we think of as "Tables" are more-formally defined as "unordered relations". Note the word "unordered" in that definition.  While table order may seem to be stable over stretches, _databases are free to re-ordered the rows on disk after insertion._ They can and will do this to make queries more efficient, conform better with indexes, fill up pages, etc.

Comment: @Chris what we can do, if the row column at least exists, is use the `row_number()` windowing function to create a new value that will be consistent between tables.

Comment: Okay, updated the answer to reflect the prior two comments.

Comment: In fact table B and table C have not relation together. Both have relation with table A with ID column. Row is just here to specify a identity  for the table B & C

Comment: @Chris Then you have a flawed schema design. You need something in the data other than row position to indicate `iR3000` should show alongside `aaaaaa` rather than `bbbbbb`.

Comment: Well i don't think so. Table B and Table C are totally independant

Comment: @Chris Clearly not, or you wouldn't be needing to show them side-by-side.

Comment: Thanks Joel, i misunderstood. You were right, i checked out the 2 tables (B and C) and each time Row column was the same. So you first solution is totally fine for what i need.